# Object Custom Properties values into a string in Geometry Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-properties

How to use Object Custom Properties values in Geometry Nodes?
Here I want an string input linked to the value of name field of the Object Custom Properties. Thanks[image]

Comment: Hello ! AFAIK this is not possible ATM.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you take it from the _Custom Properties_? Why not use the _Group Input_ as you obviously already tried according to your screenshot?